# Can I write $2>x>1$ or must I write $1<x<2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I’m thinking there’s nothing Mathematically wrong about the first, but if we’re thinking of expressing the range of a number line, the second would be clearer

Comment: Both are the same!

Comment: Both are totally fine and correct, it's more standard though to present an inequality tail starting from the least element on the left and ending at the maximal element on the right.

Comment: @Rebellos is this due to the representation on a number line, or just convention?

Comment: @Eugene Both, I'd say.

Comment: Use $2>x>1$ if you want to emphasize that $2>x$ particularly; for mathematicians who read from left-to-right the more expected writing would be $1<x<2$ so inverting it draws attention.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine:

```
2 > x > 1
```

and

```
1 < x < 2
```

But as you said, the second one is clearer for most people, because we more frequently see numbers increasing from left to right than the other way.